# Gstreamer does not play multiple streams at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gstreamer, rtsp

I am working on an app which requires to play multiple RTSP streams at a time using Gstreamer , 
it is working fine with single stream , as i add second stream , first stream stops and second starts to play , after few sconds , it also stops and app crashes.

Here is screenshot of APP streams view
[image: APP screenview]

and this screenshot when APP crashes

[image: app crash screen]

i have updates the Gstreamer.framework , searched and tried different solutions.but nothing worked

Here is my code sample for pipelining the streams

```
#import "VideoViewController.h"
#import "GStreamerBackend.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VideoViewController () {
    GStreamerBackend *gst_backend;
    GStreamerBackend *gst_backend1;
    int media_width;                /* Width of the clip */
    int media_height;               /* height ofthe clip */
    Boolean dragging_slider;        /* Whether the time slider is being dragged or not */
    Boolean is_local_media;         /* Whether this clip is stored locally or is being streamed */
    Boolean is_playing_desired;     /* Whether the user asked to go to PLAYING */
}
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
url1= my first url
url2=my second URL
```

here I initialize my 2 stream.

```
gst_backend = [[GStreamerBackend alloc] init:self videoView:video_view];

gst_backend1 = [[GStreamerBackend alloc] init:self videoView:video_view1];
```

this delegate method is called :

```
-(void) gstreamerInitialized
{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            firstInit=YES;
            play_button.enabled = TRUE;
            pause_button.enabled = TRUE;
            message_label.text = @"Ready";
            [gst_backend setUri:uri];
             [gst_backend1 setUri:uri2];
            //is_local_media = [uri hasPrefix:@"file://"];
            //is_playing_desired = NO;

           [gst_backend1 play];
             [gst_backend play];
        });

}
```

i think issue is in the search paths.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about the iOS implementation of GStreamer, but one thing to keep in mind on the Linux implementation is that you can only have one pipeline per process.  Maybe you need to use something lower level than GStreamerBackend to create a two-part pipeline?  But then you have to consider that the decode element might not readily support two simultaneous decodes...

Comment: Another thing to consider if you have control of the outgoing streams, is you could have an application wrap them up and re-encode them as a single stream to your iOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of GStreamer are you using? I remember fixing exactly that bug quite some time ago, you can find details about it here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720421

The best would be to use the newest binaries from here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.4.5/

Comment: thankx @Sebastian Droge for you answer , iam using "gstreamer-sdk-devel-2013.6-ios-universal" , when i update this with some other heigher bulid/binary , gestreamer stops working with some other erros.

Comment: i am reading links provided by you , if i face any difficulty , i will ask you, you had solve this problem before thank you mate.

Comment: Which other errors do you see? GStreamer 1.x has a slightly different API compared to 0.10 (which is what "2013.6" is based on).

Note however that GStreamer 0.10 is no longer maintained and outdated since more than 2 years now.

Comment: <gst/xoverlay.h>  not found , this error is coming again and again , i updated Gstreamer binary  and iOS version to 8.0 ,

Comment: many header files are not attaching , i think there is problem in search paths , i have added 3rd image in question , please if you can help me.

Comment: Try with the first tutorial from here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/xcode%20iOS

And then compare the settings with the ones from your project

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian , i have removed all other bugs , updated binaries , all is working fine but this weird error is coming.here :    http://postimg.org/image/v0csh3qnv/

Comment: It's <gst/video/gstvideooverlay.h> now. Also that screenshot suggests a bug in your code.

Comment: Also take a look at the ported tutorials and compare to your code. You can find them here http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/xcode%20iOS

Comment: Now i am facing problem in creating pipeline.I run the project and nothing happens , Gstreamer delegete methods are not called i.e Gstreamerinitialised is not called.This is the error in the log.I have studied some threads regarding gstreamer plugins , i did not understand them.here is my image of error log http://postimg.org/image/awpb7tt6r/

Comment: Looks like it's all working properly. The sample files there need a proper internet connection and IIRC some of them are dead links now. Try running tutorial 3, that does not depend on any external files.

Comment: i have posted the answer to this question.please check it above